# Openflow and nginx webserver

Tags: nginx, openstack

I am a newbie to openstack. I understand that neutron can be used to deploy openflow compatible network L2-L3 devices e.g ovs deployed on the fly. Can this be extended to deploying say L7 devices e.g. webservers like nginx. ?  Googling doesnt yield any tangible answers. Inputs appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neutron has been designed to cater to openstack's l2 and l3 needs alone. If you are looking for deploying other services you should take a look at the heat project.

Comment: Openstack is very modular. Each service has a specific purpose and you can add a new service without much difficulty.